# Not able to run command for maven in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, cmd, mule

I have a maven project which I want to build on Jenkins. I am giving goal as

> clean install -Desb_env=dev

I have mention esb_env in mule-app.properties file. Same command is working fine & picking up the value of esb_env in local machine.But same command is not working on jenkins. It gives error as

> Property ESB_ENV could not be found

Like this there few more goal need to give, I could not proceed further. Don't know what is wrong with Jenkins. 
I have checked path for repo as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the way we are specifying parameter in mule-app.properties file. keeping it blank & providing value through command.

```
ESB_ENV=
secure.properties=key
key=
```

Comment: no, that is not issue. I have tried both ways. I am giving property name  same as giving in mule-app.properties.

Comment: please share the files where you've defined the parameter

Comment: code for parameter is added.